# leaflet React - MarkerClusteringGroup - cannot have it working - each time casuing bugs on 'leaflets methods'

Tags: react-leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

i am having MapComponent in which i am displaying Markers.
Each time i am adding MarkerCLusteringGroup componentlibrary in the 'MapCoponent' app crashes and throwing errors on Markerk.js iconUrls issues, errors on leaflet methods 'onRemove' etc.

Below i will provide codes for 1) MapComponent 2) MarkerComponent also casuing errors 3) ClusteringComponent.

in essence case should be straightforward as i am importing 'ClusteringComponent' into 'MapCoponent' to wrap 'MarkerCoponent' for clustering on the map.
// `<CLustering><MarkersComponents/></CLustering>`.

Would appreciate for any hint how to use properly Clustering or if my 'MapCoponent' is incorrect? or is MarkerClustering incompatible with react?

1)

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import MarkerComponent from "./MarkerComponent";
import LocationMarker from "./LocationMarkerComponent";
import MarkersContext from "../context/markers-context";

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [userPosition, setUserPosition] = useState(null);
  const {
    markers,
    setMarkers,
    formSubmission,
    setFormSubmission,
    setPosition,
  } = useContext(MarkersContext);

  function UserLocationMarker() {
    const map = useMapEvents({
      click: () => {
        map.locate();
      },
      locationfound(e) {
        if (userPosition === null) {
          setUserPosition(e.latlng);
          map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom());
        }
      },
    });

    return userPosition === null ? null : (
      <LocationMarker position={userPosition} />
    );
  }

  const handleMapDoubleClick = (e) => {
    if (formSubmission !== "active") {
      const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
      const tempMarker = {
        id: markers.length + 1,
        type: "Marker",
        popup: "Drag me if needed!",
        latlng: {
          lat,
          lng,
        },
      };
      setFormSubmission("active");
      setPosition({ lat, lng });
      setMarkers([...markers, tempMarker]);
    }
  };

  // Custom hook to handle the map events
  const EventsHandler = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      dblclick: handleMapDoubleClick,
    });

    return null;
  };

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[50.054, 19.92]}
      zoom={13}
      style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
      doubleClickZoom={false}
    >
      <EventsHandler />

      <TileLayer url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png" />
      <UserLocationMarker position={userPosition} />
      {/*Marker*/}

      <MarkerComponent markers={markers} />
      {/* Search Control */}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

2. 

```
import { Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import React, { useContext, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import PopupComponent from "./PopupComponent";
import MarkersContext from "../context/markers-context";

const MarkerComponent = ({ markers, ...rest }) => {
  // Function to handle double-click event on the map
  const { formSubmission, position, setPosition } = useContext(MarkersContext);
  const markerRef = useRef(null);
  const eventHandlers = useMemo(
    () => ({
      dragend() {
        const marker = markerRef.current;
        if (marker != null) {
          const { lat, lng } = marker.getLatLng();
          setPosition({ lat, lng });
        }
      },
    }),
    [position]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {markers.map((marker) => (
        <Marker
          draggable={formSubmission === "active" ? true : false}
          key={marker.id}
          position={marker.latlng}
          eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
          ref={markerRef}
          {...rest}
        >
          <PopupComponent markerPopup={marker.popup} />
        </Marker>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MarkerComponent;
```

3. 

```
import MarkerClusterGroup from "react-leaflet-cluster";

function Clustering({ children }) {
  return <MarkerClusterGroup>{children}</MarkerClusterGroup>;
  //children are Markers refrenced in the MapCoponent where ClusteringComponent wraps it
}

export default Clustering;
```

I tried code refactorring but nothing works. Like Clustering library is incompatibilie with react